# Is there a simple way to make Sequelize return it's date/time fields in a particular format?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

We need to have sequelize return dates in a particular format, not the default one. As far as I can tell, there is no way to set that up in options, or any other way. Short of manually updating the dates every time after they are retrieved, anyone been able to solve this easily? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can define custom instance methods getDate/setDate which would translate date between sequelize internal representation and desired format like so https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#taking-advantage-of-models-being-classes

Comment: Thanks. We've decided to move away from Sequelize, but this is certainly what we needed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you end up using?

Comment: @marvin while I can read there how to setup a custom getter/setter I still don't get how I would return a formatted date there. Would you mind to elloborate this?

Comment: @mrvn the link is not available

Answer (score 41):

You can, use the Sequelize `fn` method. From the [API Reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/?highlight=sequelize.fn#fnfn-args-sequelizefn), the `fn` function will help create an object representing a SQL function in your query.

For example:

```
model.findAll({
  attributes: [
      'id',
      [sequelize.fn('date_format', sequelize.col('date_col'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 'date_col_formed']
  ]})
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Will return data values:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "date_col_formed": "2014-01-01"},
  {"id": 2, "date_col_formed": "2014-01-02"}
   // and so on...
]
```

Comment: Is there a list of the functions availables in sequelize?? It just shows the use of the `sequelize.fn` but it doesn't say what functions are available.

Comment: `sequelize.fn` just creates a object representing a database function. If you're using MySQL, you can find a list [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/func-op-summary-ref.html).

Comment: @JonSaw in my case i've two dates how to get all of them that between these dates.
how to add `$between` with `date_format`

Comment: Very good explanation. But i have to ask, if I want to make the code flexible to all the databases supported by sequelize and I use sequelize.fn, would I have to change the name of the function for different databases?

Comment: @Freya, looking at the docs & source code, it doesn't seem like Sequelize runs `fn` through any dialect translators.

Comment: In postgres, check out `to_char` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 20):

### **21/06/2019**
A little bit late but providing an update.

Sequelize is a powerful ORM (I am not saying is the best solution out there) but has a very bad documentation.

Anyway if you want to have this configured in your models one way apart from having to repeat this across your queries as other responses state you could be doing:

```
     const Test = sequelize.define('test', {
                // attributes
                name: {
                    type: DataType.STRING,
                    allowNull: false
                },
                createdAt: {
                    type: DataType.DATE,
     //note here this is the guy that you are looking for                   
                  get() {
                        return moment(this.getDataValue('createdAt')).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
                    }
                },
                updatedAt: {
                    type: DataType.DATE,
                    get() {
                        return moment(this.getDataValue('updatedAt')).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss');
                    }
                }
```

If you are using dates to provide info as: last updated, first login, last login. This is the way to go.

The function get returns the new formatted element so it should not be restricted to dates either! Just bear in mind that this will slow your query so use cautiously. ;)

more info (i know i know but docs is the name of the game): https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering to cast it as `VARCHAR` :

```php
attributes:{include:[[sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('dob'), 'VARCHAR') , 'dob']],exclude:['dob']}
```

Answer (score 1):

To format Date, you can use Sequelize.fn method. I tried all mentioned methods but it won't work with date_formate. Try to create with bellow one.

```
model.findAll({
  attributes: [
      'id',
      [sequelize.fn('FORMAT', sequelize.col('col_name'), 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'col_name']
  ]})
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

here, i used 'FORMAT' instead of 'DATE_FORMAT', because it through error :
'date_format' is not a recognized built-in function name in api call.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Model that we create using Sequelize CLI
try something like this

```
           var sequelize= require('../models');
    model.findAll({
            attributes: [
                       'id',
                       'title'
           [sequelize.Sequelize.fn('date_format', sequelize.Sequelize.col('col_name'), '%d %b %y'), 'col_name']
                            ]}.then(function(result))
                             { // dateformate=04 Nov 2017
console.log(result)
}
```

[visit this link for formate](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

For me, `date_format` and `Format` functions in above answers do not work.
I solved as below:

```
attributes: [
                [sequelize.literal('date("dateTime")'), 'dateWithoutTime'],
            ],
```