# Sequelize query timestamp format

Tags: javascript, postgresql, orm, timestamp, sequelize.js

I have a Postgresql database table with createdat and updatedat fields. They are of type timestamp with time zone, but I do not want the entire **2017-02-21 10:53:45.381712+01** when getting the created/updatedat fields. 
So I can perform this query instead:

```
select "CREATEDAT"::timestamp(0) from "MY_TABLE";
```

which returns:

```
      CREATEDAT      
---------------------
2017-02-21 10:53:45
```

Is there someway I can do the same in my Sequelize query?

Here is an example of a query that gets all columns of a entry in a table. I want to perform the above mentioned postgres query in here somewhere:

```
show: (request, reply) => {
request.models.MY_TABLE.findById(request.params.id, {

    // Maybe do something here to get right date format?

})
  .then((result) => {
    return reply(result);
  })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25278150/4583460

```
    show: (request, reply) => {
    request.models.MY_TABLE.findById(request.params.id, attributes : [
      'id',
      [sequelize.fn('date_format', sequelize.col('CREATEDAT'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'CREATEDAT']
  ])
      .then((result) => {
        return reply(result);
      })
    }
```