# Sequelize: how to get datetime column value as string

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm using Sequelize with MySQL on my Apollo GraphQL server.

Apollo part is not very important, but here's the deal.

Problem is, Sequelize is returning datetime values as Date object, when you make queries. And Apollo-Server turns the Date object to seconds(using valueOf() function of Date object) after it gets the data from the resolver. However, Apollo server only allow String datatype for Date object, so on my client's side I'm getting some thing like "385823948287" for date values.

I need to get date values as ISO String. Or any other form that moment.js accepts.

I have to make either Sequelize return DATETIME values as ISOString, or Apollo Server to make Date Objects as ISO String, not seconds in quotes.

If you know how to do just one of those jobs, please let me know.

Comment: Would it be ok to take the seconds and convert it to date?

Comment: @SanSolo I think it will get too messy if I do that job with all the data with date values in client or server side.

Comment: "Or any other form that moment.js accepts " moment.js accepts that format known as Unix/Epoch format. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847672/is-there-a-simple-way-to-make-sequelize-return-its-date-time-fields-in-a-partic/25278150#25278150) thread discusses about fetching date in specific format. The suggestion is to use Sequelize.fn method

Comment: @SanSolo Thanks, that's also a solution, but the problem is I have to Sequelize.fn everytime I make queries on date values. I wanted a solution that requires no additional care afterwards. The answer I wrote below however fixed the problem, not with sequelize though. I hope there's an option when you initiate sequelize that makes models return date values as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using [Graphql ISO Date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-iso-date). Now I'm getting proper date string.

Install the module,  add `scalar DateTime` and change the data types of date values to `DateTime` in your schema. Import the module and add it as `DateTime` on your type resolver.

Comment: Could you show how you fixed it? I have exactly the same problem but I was not able to understand what you did as the Graphql ISO Data website don't explain about it.

Comment: @wondim I think what I wrote in the answer best describes what you have to do. 
1. Install the module.
2. Add scalar DateTime in your schema.
3. Change the type of regarding fields.

Comment: Did you use `GraphQLDateTime`?

Comment: It's Graphql ISO Date.