# Store createAt and updatedAt as epoch unix timestamps instead of Date in Postgres Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm new to Postgres. I am using it via Sequelize. I am not sure how to create models in my node.js app so that when rows are inserted in my tables the time is specified as epoch unix timestamp:

```
1583855009
```

instead of:
[image]

I tried changing my models like this:

```
  createdAt: {
    type: 'TIMESTAMP',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
    allowNull: false
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: 'TIMESTAMP',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
    allowNull: false
  }
```

but it did not work. When refreshing the table with pgAdmin it still shows what you seen in the picture here instead of a timestamp like "1583855009".

Is there a way to store "1583855009" instead?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp stored in postgres is just another representation of the same information as the number of milliseconds since epoch time.

Once the timestamp fields are extracted from the database, [`Date.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) can be used in order to get the desired number format.

Illustration in the snippet below:

```js
// replace line below by query retrieving timestamp from the database
let valuefromDB = new Date('2020-03-10T09:36:04.071')

console.log(valuefromDB.valueOf())
```

Comment: ok, I think I can follow this pattern, so, if I want to get a user straight out of the DB and send it out as json (something like this: res.status(200).json(user);), how can that createdAt be a unix timestamp instead of the '2020-03-10T09:36:04.071' ...? I am trying to avoid having to put a middle step in there and thought the only way was to store the '1583832964071' straight in the table...

Comment: Well, both values being equivalent, the value returned by sequelize can be sent directly to the client without further processing. Otherwise, solutions using [`sequelize.fn`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn) or a [custom get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56697250) can be set in the model definition, as one can easily find using a search engine and reading the docs.