# PostgreSQL - how to convert timestamp with timezone to timestamp without timezone

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my PostgreSQL database, the datetime stored as ***2022-05-10 10:44:19+08*** and when I get
the datetime by using the sequelize, it will give in format:: ***2022-05-10T02:44:19.000Z***.

So, my question is how to convert to ***2022-05-10 10:44:19*** ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to make Sequelize return it's date/time fields in a particular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847672/is-there-a-simple-way-to-make-sequelize-return-its-date-time-fields-in-a-partic)

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct dependence on the time of your server. Therefore, depending on what you want to get, you can use different options.
Here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0c795c981e8b947fda07e4e2de1cfeb6) with examples