# Sequelize format date

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables `Posts` and `Likes`.

and `Posts` table associated to `Likes` table by `hasMany`.

I'm trying to select all the posts and include the likes that belongs to it.

The Question is how to format the datetime or (createdAt).

I use NodeJS, ExpressJS, Sequelize and MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Get posts function:

```js
router.get("/", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const listOfPosts = await Posts.findAll({
    include: [Likes],
    order: [["createdAt", "desc"]],
  });

  const likedPosts = await Likes.findAll({ where: { UserId: req.user.id } });
  res.json({ listOfPosts: listOfPosts, likedPosts: likedPosts });
});
```

Posts Model:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Posts = sequelize.define("Posts", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    postText: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  Posts.associate = (models) => {
    Posts.hasMany(models.Comments, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });

    Posts.hasMany(models.Likes, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    });
  };

  return Posts;
};
```

Comment: _The Question is how to format the datetime or (createdAt)_ For sending to the database, or for some other process?

Comment: MySQL DATETIME data type has to be `CCYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I'm making an api and i want to format the mysql datetime to (d-m-y) format.

Comment: So when you read it, in its correct native format from MySQL that is when you reformat it to however the front end requires to see it. You do not try and store date times in some other format on the database as that will lose ALL the standard date and time processing goodies

Comment: @RiggsFolly Exactly.

Comment: So is your question..... How do I reformat a `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` date time string into a `d-m-y` string in javascript?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, but I would to format it in the server.

Comment: This is how you can do per model. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56697250/2956135
I thought there is a way to intercept globally but cannot find it at a moment.

Comment: @Emma Thanks, but i don't  want to change the model structure.

Comment: It is not changing. `get` function in attribute is called when Sequelize serialize the response.  It is called after Sequelize fetch data from DB.  `createdAt` or `updatedAt` is generated automatically if it is not defined in your model, so no additional attributes are created by adding `createdAt` with `get` function in your model.  (Unless you manually says `timestamps: false` in Sequelize initialization).

Answer (score 0):

`createdAt` parameter is accepted by Node.js as a regular `Date` instance.
You can retrieve parts or the date to build format as you wish.

```js
let date = post.createdAt;

let day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
let month = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
let year = date.getFullYear().toString()

let hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')
let minutes = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')


let dateFormatted = `${day}.${month}.${year} ${hours}:${minutes}`;

console.log(dateFormatted);
```

`padStart` is used to have one heading zero if number has only one digit, like here: `01.05.2022`. The same for hours and minutes, you can remove it as you wish.
Month is increased by 1, because `January is 0`, so to be readable for user, we need to increment it.

Better practice is to move date formatting to `function`